# Passing keyfile to create LUKS header

Tags: disk-encryption, luks, dm-crypt

The dm-crypt LUKS utility '**cryptsetup**' allows us to specify the ***key-file*** in place of ***passphrase***. Looking at the code for cryptsetup I understand that if ***key-file*** is specified, the ***passphrase*** is not used.

I now want to do that using LUKS API `crypt_format`. But, `crypt_format` does not provide an option to specify key-file. A new keyslot can be added later using keyfile, but initially passphrase is required.

I don't want to use passphrase. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This seems more suited to stackoverflow, it seems only tangentially related to security.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the cryptsetup source, the relevant parts are [here](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/v1_7_5/src/cryptsetup.c#L736) and [here](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/v1_7_5/src/utils_password.c#L115), it looks like cryptsetup is reading the key from the keyfile if it's set, or stdin otherwise. [crypt_get_key](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/v1_7_5/lib/utils_crypt.c#L331) seems to be mostly just reading the file up to DEFAULT_KEYFILE_SIZE_MAXKB with a lot of extra handling going on, and [crypt_get_key_tty](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/v1_7_5/lib/utils_crypt.c#L229) looks similar, so I'd guess that you could just read the file and use its contents as the passphrase.